# Rails dosn't reload class under ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I start up rails server like this:

```
$rails server thin -d
```

My env is development, for sure.

If request isn't ajax, classes reload.

On client side, I use jQuery for ajax requests.

Snippet on client-side:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/products/all',
    success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
 }
```

});

**How to force Rails reload classes under ajax request?**

Comment: it's hard to say without looking at jquery code

Comment: @metal_fan, I have provided jQuery code as you wanted.